# Error when trying to install jest-cli

Tags: jestjs, npm-install

When I run `npm install --save-dev jest-cli` to install Jest, I get the following error:

```
> jest-cli@0.10.0 postinstall /var/www/html/_learning/react/hacking-book/node_modules/jest-cli
> node postinstall.js

{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./setup.sh
/bin/sh: 1: ./setup.sh: not found
]
  killed: false,
  code: 127,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c ./setup.sh' }
```

I downloaded `setup.sh` from the jest GitHub repo (https://github.com/facebook/jest) and ran it manually. I then ran `npm install` again with the same results as above. How can I get Jest installed?